# Dropped too fast or too fastly?

Tags: grammar, adverbs

Let's say you watched a war-related movie, wherein the bomb was dropping down a city. And then, you storytell it to your interested friend.

> Oh man, the movie was so intense! The aircraft dropped the bomb **too fast!/ too fastly!**

I think I've heard or read the usage of **too fast** similar to my example, and this is ungrammatical(I think) that even natives say that.

So is this an exception to the grammar rules now?

Comment: Ah! Did you mean to say "the bomb was dropped too soon", or "the bomb was dropped too early"? Also, an aircraft does not drop a bomb, it carries a bomb, and a crew member or machine decides when to drop it. But the bomb, once released, always falls at the same speed, so it cannot be "too fast", and definitely not **too fastly** because **fastly** is not a word.

Comment: @WeatherVane, thx for the info. about the function of aircrafts, but seriously, do I really have to be so literal about it? Can it be understood if I just use aircraft dropping the bomb and not a crew or a pilot?

Comment: Agree with Weather Vane. When a plane drops a bomb, it falls at the speed decided by gravity. It can't fall 'too fast'.

Comment: When a bomb falls out of a plane, it doesn't "fall at the same speed" during all of its journey to the ground. It is accelerated by gravity to a terminal velocity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many adverbs end in *-ly*, but not all of them do.  *Fast* can be an adjective, but in this case *fast* is an adverb, and there's nothing non-standard or ungrammatical about it.  *Fastly*, on the other hand, would be ungrammatical; *fast* is already an adverb, and there's no need to add *-ly*.

[Dictionaries aren't always right about parts of speech](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjY9qnM_aHcAhWsVN8KHcJsDTgQFghDMAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fling.ed.ac.uk%2F~gpullum%2FZAA_final_proof.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2m4QRUdguMUluQSnS8HJ3x), but in this case they'll give you the right answer.  [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/fast_2), for example, defines *fast* as an adverb which means 'quickly'.  As you've noticed yourself, this usage is quite common.

*Too fast* isn't especially informal, but in formal speech it might be better to say *too quickly* instead.

Comment: I think you get my point. In a nutshell, the word fast is a unique one huh, it can be an adverb too(I already know it is an adjective, that is why I'm learning what is the adverb of it)

Comment: @JohnArvin an interesting question, since we say "slow" and "fast"; "slowly" but not "fastly".

Comment: @JohnArvin It's actually not *unique*, but there aren't a whole lot of flat adverbs in Standard English.  One flat adverb learners have to be particularly careful of is [*hard*](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/hard_2).  *Hard* can be an adjective or an adverb, while [*hardly*](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/hardly) is a different word with a different meaning, not the adverb form of *hard*.  It's important not to mix them up.